# Create index in kibana without using kibana

Tags: elasticsearch, indexing, configuration, logstash, kibana

I'm very new to the elasticsearch-kibana-logstash and can't seem to find solution for this one.

I'm trying to create index that I will see in kibana without having to use the POST command in Dev Tools section.

I have set test.conf-

```
input {
 file {
   path => "/home/user/logs/server.log"
   type => "test-type"
   start_position => "beginning"
 }
}

output {
 elasticsearch {
  hosts =>  ["localhost:9200"]
  index => "new-index"
 }
}
```

and then

`bin/logstash -f test.conf` from logstash directory

what i get is that I can't find the new-index in kibana (index patterns section), when I use elasticsearch - `http://localhost:9200/new-index/` it presents an error and when I go to `http://localhost:9600/` (the port it's showing) it doesn't seem to have any errors

Thanks a lot for the help!!

Comment: What do you mean is that you can't find the `new-index` which you're trying to create using `logstash`, in your indices list in `http://localhost:9200`?

Comment: Can't find it in kibana.. Isn't it suppose to get there...?

Comment: I also tried to set `hosts =>  ["http://localhost:5601/"]` (kibana's port) with no success either

Comment: No it will not automatically appear in Kibana, you have to create it there in Management > Add New with the same name of the indice you've created using logstash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have actually succeeded to create index even without first creating it in Kibana

I used the following config file -

```
input {
  file {
    path => "/home/hadar/tmp/logs/server.log"
    type => "test-type"
    id => "NEWTRY"
    start_position => "beginning"
 }
}

filter {
  grok {
    match => { "message" => "%{YEAR:year}-%{MONTHNUM:month}-%{MONTHDAY:day} %{HOUR:hour}:%{MINUTE:minute}:%{SECOND:second} - %{LOGLEVEL:level} - %{WORD:scriptName}.%{WORD:scriptEND} - " }
  }
}

output {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts =>  ["localhost:9200"]
    index => "new-index"
    codec => line { format => "%{year}-%{month}-%{day} %{hour}:%{minute}:%{second} - %{level} - %{scriptName}.%{scriptEND} - \"%{message}\"" }
  }
}
```

I made sure that the index wasn't already in Kibana (I tried with other indexes names too just to be sure...) and eventually I did see the index with the log's info in both Kibana (I added it in the index pattern section) and Elasticsearch when I went to `http://localhost:9200/new-index`

The only thing I should have done was to erase the `.sincedb_XXX` files which are created under `data/plugins/inputs/file/` after every Logstash run

OR

the other solution (for tests environment only) is to add `sincedb_path=>"/dev/null"` to the input file plugin which indicates to not create the `.sincedb_XXX` file

Answer (score 0):

It's obvious that you won't be able to find the index which you've created using `logstash` in Kibana, unless you're manually creating it there within the `Managemen` section of `Kibana`.

Make sure, that you have the same name of the indice which you created using `logstash`. Have a look at the [doc](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/tutorial-define-index.html), which conveys:

> When you define an index pattern, indices that match that pattern must
>   exist in Elasticsearch. Those indices must contain data.

which pretty much says that the indice should exist for you to create the index in `Kibana`. Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks I guess I miss understood the concept of those tools... I thought it is all one connected tool but I guess it's not

Comment: Yes that's right. It's basically a stack of products which has it's own way of being handled. But then ES acts as the core around the stack.

Answer (score 0):

You can create directly index in elastic search using https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-create-index.html
and these indices can be used in Kibana.